# Drawing Decision tree with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I working on a draw decision tree with python,

```
tree.plot_tree(clf.fit(X_train, y_train))
plt.suptitle("Decision surface of a decision tree using paired features")
plt.show()
```

but when I run this code, the tree shows up like this

Decision Tree

[image]

Is there any possible way to make the tree normal?

Comment: Have you tried changing some options, such as font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[export_graphviz](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) might be a good alternative for you.

Here is a [Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/willkoehrsen/visualize-a-decision-tree-w-python-scikit-learn) that explains how to make the best use of this functionality provided by sklearn.

For the plot_tree function you are using you can try changing the font size using the `fontsize` argument. Or you can also try changing the size of the figure if you haven't already done that by doing something like this -

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(x, y) #dimensions you want
```